# Jasmine Node javascript promise testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I want to test some promises with jasmine node. However, the test runs but it says that there are 0 assertions. This is my code, is there something wrong? The then part is successfully called, so if I have a console.log there, it gets called. If I have the code test a http request, on the success, the assertion is correctly interpretated.

```
describe('Unit tests', function () {
it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    service.getAllClients().then(function (res) {
        expect("hello world").toEqual("hello world");
        done();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        fail();
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Where are `done` and `fail` defined? Did you read the [documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)? It seems everything you'd need to know is in there.

Comment: It's from the jasmine framework themself, no?

Comment: [`fail` yes](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Manually_failing_a_spec_with_<code>fail</code>). Didn't see anything about `done`. But again, look at the documentation. It should be pretty clear what your mistake is.

Comment: How would you test a promise then?

Comment: Look at the examples in the docs: *"Calls to `beforeAll`, `afterAll`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, and `it` can take an optional single argument that should be called when the async work is complete."* . What is it you don't understand about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `done` argument to the callback you pass to `it`, so Jasmine knows you are testing something asynchronously:

```
it("contains spec with an expectation", function(done) {
    // ...
```

When you include that parameter, Jasmine will wait for a while for you to call `done` so it knows when you're done.

```
    done();
```

Secondly, in an asynchronous test, it probably is better to fail with a call of `done.fail`:

```
    done.fail();
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by myself, I accepted your answer though because it was the one I needed